# How to check marker is with in direction?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app in android using Google Map, I want to check if a marker is in direction from A to B or not ?

[image]

Comment: So, you want to know if your marker is on a given path?

Comment: yes , I want to check oranges marker is on blue way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.isLocationOnPath` method from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) that, according to [the Javadoc](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java):

> Computes whether the given point lies on or near a polyline, within a specified
>   tolerance in meters. The polyline is composed of great circle segments if geodesic
>   is true, and of Rhumb segments otherwise. The polyline is not closed -- the closing
>   segment between the first point and the last point is not included.